# How to Optimize this Code?Code for Fibonacci-Prime?

Tags: c

My Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isprime(long int n);
int isfib(long int n);

int main()
{
    int t;
    long int i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&i);
        if(isprime(i))
        {
            printf("%d\n",isfib(i));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
    }
}

int isprime(long int n)
{
    int j;
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(j=2;j<=n/2;j++)
    {
        if(n%j==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int isfib(long int n)
{
   long int a=0,b=1,c=0;
    while(1)
    {
        c=a+b;
        if(c<n)
        {
          a=b;
          b=c; 
        }
        else if(c==n)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

T is no. of test cases.

**Input** 3 2 4

**Output** 1 1 0

Code is correct. But I want to execute with O(n)complexity.

Could you please me to, how to optimize this code, I want to learn code optimization in only this c programming language.

**ERROR** Your program took more time than expected.
expected time>1.12Sec

Comment: There are much better algorithms to do what you want to do that is easy to find if you search.

Comment: There are some ways you could optimize this code. First of all, you are computing the `isFib` and `isPrime` again if the input is the same. Maybe you can store it somewhere. Also, your `isPrime` can be further optimized by only iterating till `sqrt(n)`. Also, you are calculating Fibonacci numbers till again and again, storing it can give a lot of speed up.

Comment: This is obvously some online competition of some sort. You should link it in the question.

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/the-fibonacci-prime-number/0

Comment: The upper limit of 10^^75 for the possible values is far beyond what a 64 bit integer can store.  You'll need to find some alternate method that doesn't involve storing the full number as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have a very slow implementation of `isprime`. This one is way faster:

```
int isprime(int n) {
    if(n == 1) return 0;
    int i=2;
    while(i*i<n) {
        if(n%i == 0)
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can find something similar online for the fibonacci sequence.

However, it seems like you will receive a pretty big amount of numbers. Then it's a waste checking the same number again. You can use the following idea to take advantage of that.

```
int isprimeandsaveresult(int n, char * arr) {
    if(arr[n] == 1) return 1;
    if(arr[n] == 0) return 0;
    return arr[n] = isprime(n);
}
```

Here, `arr` is a huge array initialized to something else than `1` or `0`. I chose `char` to save memory, but this can be improved further by some hash function. You can use the same principle for fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I am quite new to programming when compared to some veterans so correct me if I'm mistaken. I see no pointers in your code that means some of your variables could be converted into register storage class.

Register class variables are stored in CPU registers not in memory so for frequently used variables it is very nice for optimization. In your case "i" is strongly recommend but this can be implemented to all your variables.

Comment: Such microoptimizations is definetely the wrong way to go here.